# can't find preg matches for a string and sort them into array

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find preg match_all for the ISBN for this lines:

```
<td itemprop="isbn">9789953278544</td></tr>
<td itemprop="isbn">9789953278535</td></tr>
<td itemprop="isbn">9789953278568</td></tr>
```

I've tried:

```
preg_match_all('|<td itemprop="isbn">(.+?)"</td></tr>|si', '<td itemprop="isbn">9789953278544</td></tr><td itemprop="isbn">9789953278535</td></tr><td itemprop="isbn">9789953278568</td></tr>', $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $connect[1][0];
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag[1] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: How about using an HTML parser instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this search pattern .

**My code**

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/<td itemprop="isbn">(.+?)<\/td><\/tr>/', '<td itemprop="isbn">9789953278544</td></tr><td itemprop="isbn">9789953278535</td></tr><td itemprop="isbn">9789953278568</td></tr>', $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag[1] . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

**output**

```
9789953278544<br>9789953278535<br>9789953278568<br>
```

Comment: try escaping the '/'  with '\'